# How would I calculate the energy released during an average Old Faithful geyser eruption?

Tags: energy, pressure, water

I am working on a  comparison between the electrical energy our company saved through energy efficiency and the energy needed to "power" an Old Faithful (OF) eruption. I found an estimate that OF releases 1MW during an average eruption, but that was the only estimate and I couldn't validate it elsewhere.

So, here's what we know: https://www.nps.gov/places/old-faithful-geyser.htm

- Note, I took the mean of the data points provided by NPS
- An average eruption lasts between 1.5 and 5 minutes (call it 3.25 minutes)
- During an eruption, between 3,700 and 8,400 gallons of water are ejected (6,050 gallons)
- The height of an OF erutpion can reach between 106 and 184 feet (145 feet)

Calculating the amount of energy it takes to push a gallon of water 145 feet is fairly straightforward; however, I am not sure how to (or if I need to) factor in the duration of an eruption.

Also, I am not sure if I would need to take into account the amount of energy required to superheat water to 350*F. Volcanic activity is constantly radiating heat into the cavity below  OF. It is the potential energy of the stored water and steam that we are interested in.

So, the question for you all is: How many joules of energy are released during an average eruption of Old Faithful?

Thank you!

Comment: "So, here's what we know..." What do you mean? How did you get this starting data?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not providing a link to the data. The post has been edited accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are these 8400 gallons released in total? If so, then you could just use MGH=Eg and substitute M for density times volume, which for water is 8.34 * 8400 = 70056 lb or 31776 kg, ejected 140 feet, or about 42 meters. Then, we set the reference for H=0 to the ground; after all this we can see that 9,8 * 31776 * 42 is about 13 kilojoules of energy, over 270 seconds, gives us about 0.04 kW or 40 Watts of power.
Since this seems very low, so I expect this information isn't for total gallons, but instead for a volume per time. Even then, it wouldn't be very hard to calculate; you'd just do the exact same thing, but in the start, the mass would be volume * density * time, the time would be 270 seconds in whatever unit they use, be it minutes or seconds, and remember to convert.

Edit: Since i can't comment as a guest, I'd like to add that other than for power calculations, or the volume being gallons per some unit of time, no, you wouldn't need to take time into account. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! So, following your formula and the updated data, I have an equation that looks like this:

(9.81 m/s^2)(42m)(22,886.91kg) = 9429.86 kJ
I directly converted to kJ since it takes 9.8j to lift 1kg 1 meter

If this math is correct, do I still need to account for the duration of the eruption? 
Thanks!